# Is there a way to read transcription of IRC Office hours somewhere?

Tags: android

tried to attend some of the office hours but there were some problems with the IRC, so it was very difficult to follow the discussion. Are the past sessions recorded somewhere ?

It would be great if the "best" topics are summarized and posted, so other people who wasn't at the particular discussion have the knowledge as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We do not provide the transcripts, however all the questions asked during the office hours and their answers are archived here under the tags android+fromirc.